# Requesting exhaustive docs on web components technology

Tags: dom, polymer, web-component

I've been working with Web Components (Polymer) for some time and I've read all the references that I know of, both those on the standard and on the Polymer Project. IMHO, most of them (especially, Shadow DOM x01) are pretty good starting points as tutorial-oriented resources. My personal congrats and thanks to their authors. Nevertheless, what I'm needing now is an exhaustive documentation regarding the new web component technologies. Info about each new element type, each new method, each new attribute, each new event, etc., and, in general, each new API extension that could have been added on the existing elements.

Up to my knowledge and to my surprise, the W3C specs do not include all these details that I mentioned before or an exhaustive and extensive list of them.

Is there any such kind of complete documentation though it were in a heavy formal format, that I could read to ensure that nothing is slipping my grasp of this technology?

Thanks in advance,

Nacho

Comment: Feel free to comment with more specific follow ups if my answer below doesn't answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

When I've had trouble tracking down info on the relevent specs it's been because I was reading out of date versions. Here are the latest versions of the main web component specs.:

- [Custom Elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)
- [Shadow Dom](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/)
- [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/)

The Shadow DOM spec adds [a couple of elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#the-content-element) in addition to some new [attributes and methods](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#attributes-1) to existing elements.

The Custom Element spec adds [`registerElement`](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#extensions-to-document-interface-to-register) as well as extending [`createElement` and `createElementNS`](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#extensions-to-document-interface-to-instantiate) on `document`, and it adds a handful of [events on custom elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#types-of-callbacks).

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I already had read those documents. Nevertheless, I have a disquieting feeling about the scattered nature of the documentation, not to say that, being a part standard and another Polymer documentation, I couldn't find a formal description à la W3C of the Polymer extensions. For example, is there any place where I could find the data binding templates interface? Same for the Mutation Observers and things of the sort.

Comment: Mutation Observers spec can be found here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers but template data binding isn't part of any specs that I know of. That's purely a Polymer feature and you can read more about it on the Polymer api docs: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html